# Is dropshipping halal?

Tags: halal-haram

I just wanted to know if dropshipping business is halal. I found a video on youtube by Sheikh Assim al Hakeem who says that dropshipping is not permissible. Other than that, I did not find any other sources that directly say that dropshipping is haram.
The link to Sheikhs video is here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9BrIHPzPc64

Comment: As far as I know -i might be wrong - in Islam you can't sell something which is not in your possession at the moment of selling. And that could be an issue here if I understand correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Drop shipping is not halal under the three given scenarios:

1. Selling something that one does not own, unless it is done in the form of a salam transaction [payment in advance], in accordance with the guidelines thereon.
2. Selling something that one has bought but not yet taken possession of .
3. Selling gold, silver or currency without the exchange taking place on the spot, in the place where the deal was drawn up.

---

### Selling something that one does not own

There are clear sahih hadiths concerning it, such as the report narrated by an-Nasai (4613), Abu Dawud (3503) and at-Tirmidhi (1232) from Hakim ibn Hizam, who said:

> A man may come to me, looking to buy something from me, so I go to the marketplace and buy it, then I sell it to him. The Prophet (blessings and peace of Allah be upon him) said: “Do not sell that which you do not possess.” (classed as sahih by al-Albani in Sahh an-Nasai)

At-Tirmidhi (1234), Abu Dawud (3504) and an-Nasai (4611) narrated from ‘Amr ibn Shu‘ayb, from his father, that his grandfather said:

The Messenger of Allah (blessings and peace of Allah be upon him) said:

> “It is not permissible to arrange a loan combined with a sale, or to stipulate two conditions in one transaction, or to make a profit on something that is not under your control, or to sell something that you do not possess.” (Classed as sahih by at-Tirmidhi and al-Albani)

*This is a unanimous view.*

### Selling something that one has bought but not yet taken possession of

The hadith of Hakim ibn Hizaam that is quoted above indicates that if you buy an item, you cannot sell it until you take possession of it.

This was narrated by Ahmad (15316) and an-Nasai (4613), and classed as sahih by al-Albani in Sahih al-Jami‘ (342).

This includes food and other things, so it is not permissible to sell what you have bought before you take possession of it. *This is the view of ash-Shafi'i, in contrast to those of the scholars who limited this prohibition to food.*

### Selling gold, silver or currency without the exchange taking place on the spot, in the place where the deal was drawn up.

It is prohibited to sell gold, silver or currency for another of this category without the exchange taking place on the spot.

---

**However this transaction can be made halal**

- By making it a salam transaction, in accordance with the guidelines thereon.
- By making it a profit-sharing transaction.
- By acting as an agent for the customers, on condition that you take money from them and buy items with it, and you do not buy items with your own money then ask them to pay you back.
- By acting as an agent for the original shop.

---

[Reference](https://www.google.com/amp/s/islamqa.info/amp/en/answers/334744)

### For more about permissibility of Dropshipping see :

- [Is purchase from drop shipping permissible?](https://islamqa.org/hanafi/askimam/5834/1is-purchase-from-drop-shipping-permissible-2where-should-the-non-baligh-children-stand-in-jamaat/) by askimam
- [Is Dropshipping Permissible in Islam](https://ilmfeed.com/dropshipping-permissible-islam/) by Ilmfeed
- [Cases When Dropshipping Is Permissible](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.islamweb.net/amp/en/fatwa/378148/) by islamweb

---

Answer (score 0):

No is haram and also illegal in some part of the word example :
if you live in the EU and you post a listing saying that you have an object but when a customer buy it but you say you dont have it, he can sue you
An italian article (use google translate) where some online dropshipper get sued
https://www.hwupgrade.it/news/web/l-agcm-sanziona-tre-siti-e-commerce-italiani-per-pratiche-scorrette_57372.html

Comment: Please add references!

Answer (score -5):

i think it is, because it's a trade, You're taking new products which helps people live better from chinese suppliers, and showing them if they wanna buy and then purchasing it from the supplier, it may gets a bit haraam if you use ads which shows nudity or anything which isn't permissible in islam. so try to use male figures for products , womens are good for women products, thanks. and make sure to target womens , and ads for women products should be modest.